# JSF Component state of <h:selectOneMenu> didnt change for page refresh

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I would like to get my JSF Component Dropdown boxes initialized for each page refresh. I already knows that JSF maintains the previous state, but is there any way that i can re-initialize the `<h:selectOneMenu>` Component on each page refresh. My Backing bean is SessionScoped and I cannot change it, since i am using `<f:ajax>` tag to fire a backing bean method on each onChange event of this dropdown boxes. Please help me to the solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/) can solve your issue. You simply need to reset the property that's binded to that `<h:selectOneMenu>` before render the view.

Comment: That event will be invoked on every request. You'd need to check if it's a postback or not.

Comment: @BalusC I thought that this event would only happen once before the view is rendered. Do you mean that subsequent ajax calls will also trigger this event?

Comment: Yes. Surely the view is (re)rendered on every request. How else should the client get new response?

Comment: @BalusC: well, it seems I didn't fully understand the update process. I thought that if we specify `<f:ajax render="someID" />`, only the component with `id="someID"` will be re-rendered, not the whole view.

Comment: Partial renders are also renders.

Answer (score 0):

> *since i am using `<f:ajax>` tag to fire a backing bean method on each onChange event of this dropdown boxes*

For among others exactly this reason, the view scope is been invented. Put the bean in the view scope instead.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    // ...
}
```

Each browser window/tab will get its own view scoped bean and every page refresh will recreate it. It'll also immediately fix the potential major trouble caused by unintuitive page behaviour when the user has the same page open in different browser windows/tabs in the same session while you're using a session scoped bean.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. But i am using '@Named' annotation and I cannot use '@ViewScoped', instead i had checked with '@ConversationScoped'...still there is no use '<f:ajax>' never fired its Listener method on the backing bean. Infact i had raised this question yesterday. I found it working only with '@SessionScoped' bean at '@Named' annotation.

Comment: Using a session scoped bean to hold view scoped data is a very bad idea. What exactly is the reason that you want to use CDI annotations instead of JSF annotations? By the way, the `@ConversationScoped` requires you to manually start and end the injected `Conversation` object. Alone the annotation is not sufficient. See also the javadoc of the annotation for an example.

Comment: As u suggested i had injected 'javax.enterprise.context.Conversation' and started the conversation.begin() on '@PostConstruct' method. Still no use <f:ajax> listener didnt get fired. Is there any way that i can use my CDI annotated beans into backing bean classes annotated with '@ManagedBean'.

Comment: No. You have now 2 options: 1) Just don't use CDI. Or 2) Figure why CDI works bad on your environment. You still have not elaborated what exactly is the reason that you're using CDI annotations instead of JSF annotations. If there are no technical reasons, just use JSF annotations instead. If there are technical reasons, please elaborate them in detail. Most likely the same is just possible with JSF annotations as well.